# 'variable was not declared in this scope' while accessing global variable from a derived class's constructor

Tags: c++, class, g++

I have two classes in my application code. I divided the application into three files. One the header file **'header.h'** , another is a cpp file **'header.cpp'** in which all functions used are defined. Finally the main.cpp file that I am compiling using g++ compiler. Following are the contents of all three files.

**1) header.h**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct table
{
        unsigned int num;
        string entry;
};

typedef struct table Table;

Table Randomstuff[]={
        {10,"Alphabets"},
        {6,"Numbers"},
        {8,"Words"},
        {6,"Sentences"},
        {6,"Phrases"},
        {8,"Idioms"}
};

class basics
{
        /*data members*/
        public:
                basics();
                void Display(void);
};

class afterbasics: public basics
{
    /*Data members*/
    public:
           afterbasics();
           void Display(void);
};
```

**2) header.cpp**

```
basics::basics()
{
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        cout<<Randomstuff[i].entry<<endl;
    }
}
```

**3) main.cpp**

```
#include"header.h"
#include"header.cpp"

int main()
{
       afterbasics obj;
       obj.Display();
}
```

I compile the `main.cpp` file using `g++ main.cpp[RETURN]` and I get the following error.

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
header.cpp: In constructor ‘basics::basics()’:
header.cpp:17:9: error: ‘Randomstuff’ was not declared in this scope
   cout<<Randomstuff[i].entry<<endl;
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Also I am new to posting on stackoverflow, any inputs would help.

Comment: Did you try including header.h?

Comment: You will not understand C++ until you understand C++' compilation model. You need to be able to answer this question: Which files get compiled by your compiler?

Comment: `#include"header.cpp"` don't include cpp files

Comment: @Kevin I believe #include"header.cpp" is fine because it is only file copying into expanded source file. It is not illegal right? Compiler compiles the expanded source file

Comment: @IInspectable compiler compiles expanded source file and I am basically copying global variables, functions into main.cpp using preprocessor directives that generates expanded source file. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `header.cpp` needs `#include header.h`

Comment: Yes that worked.  Also I had to remove that inclusion from```main.cpp```